# Materialize carousel failing to disable draggable property

Tags: javascript, html, materialize

I'm using materialize carousel library, and the default is having it draggable (Mobile UX benefits I guess). I want to disable it since it's interrupts scrolling on mobile devices.

I've tried to apply `draggable` property as `false`, yet it still continues to work.

Here is my slider code

```js
//Slider
$('.carousel.carousel-slider').carousel({
        fullWidth: true,
        indicators: true,
        draggable: false
});
autoplay();
function autoplay() {
        $('.carousel.carousel-slider').carousel('next');
        setTimeout(autoplay, 5500);
}
```

```css
.carousel{
    height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <!-- SLIDER -->
        <div class="carousel carousel-slider" data-indicators="true" style="z-index: 0;">
            <div class="carousel-item white lighten-2 white-text" href="#one!" style="height: 100%; background-size: cover; background-image: url('./images/tunnel.webp'); background-position: 60% center;">
                <div class="container">
                    <h2>Real time tracking</h2>
                    <p class="white-text">
                        Our devices allows you to track you employee in real time.<br/>
                        Gives you full control on your mine personnel.<br/>
                        Incase of injuries, you know where to search.<br/>
                        Knowing how to deploy your forces.<br/>
                        Efficiency at her best.
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item white darken-2 white-text" href="#two!" style="background-size: cover; background-image: url('./images/planning.webp'); background-position: 60% center;">
                <div class="container">
                  <h4><span style="color: blue">EURO</span>TECH</h4>
                  <h2>It's all about efficiency & safety</h2>
                  <p class="white-text">
                      You can either choose to work <span style="border-bottom: 1px solid red;">harder</span> or you can work <span style="border-bottom: 1px solid blue;">smarter</span>
                  </p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item white white-text" href="#three!" style="background-image: url('./images/header.webp'); background-position: center center;">
                <div class="container" style="text-align: center; margin: 25em auto;">

                    <h2>Avoiding the next disaster</h2>
                    <p class="white-text">
                      Together we can prevent the next case with unique underground tracking devices,<br/>
                      digital solutions and advanced mining products.
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="scroller">
              <a href="#info"><span></span>Scroll</a>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Here is the [result](https://www.yotamdahan.com/eurotech/)

How can I disable mobile draggable carousel option? Or solve the scrolling down sensitivity issue.

Comment: Is draggable an option in Materialize? Just checked the docs - I can't see it. That would definitely explain why it isn't working :) https://materializecss.com/carousel.html

Comment: Maybe have a dig around, i just found this: https://www.thetopsites.net/article/51849366.shtml

Comment: @SeanDoherty I've already reached that page, tried applying the scripts they've suggested.. I guess materialize has changed since then.

Comment: Ok, well as you can see from the carousel page, `draggable' isn't an option (I think it's an option available for sidenav). Also...when I run your code snippet, it's just throws an error...and when I visit the link you provided on mobile, the carousel doesn't show up at all (shows up fine on desktop)

Comment: @SeanDoherty yes, that happens only on iphone.. I'm trying to solve that also. I guess I will just switch API source.